# Loading MailKit DLL as Assembly in Powershell

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly, mailkit

I'm trying to use MailKit dll as assembly in Powershell but there is no way it works.
I've tried with add-type and  with [System.Reflection.Assembly] methods bwithout success.
The link to mailkit library:

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

With this method :

```
 $path="$HOME\.nuget\packages\mailkit\1.16.1\lib\net451\MailKit.dll" 
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($path)
```

ther isn't reference to the assembly in memory.
With this method :

```
Add-Type -Path $path
```

this is the error:

> - Add-Type -Path $path
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Thanks

Daniele

Comment: Post the actual code you're using, the error message(s), and how you installed the DLL. People here can't guess at what you've done/are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the path. For me works just fine with the absolute path in `$MailKitDllPath`:

```
  Add-Type -Path $MailKitDllPath
  $client = New-Object MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient
```

Answer (score 4):

this full script may help others:

```
# search for "Test" in subject and MoveTo Archive/2018

$packages = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
add-type -path (Join-Path $packages "MimeKit.dll") | Out-Null
add-type -path (Join-Path $packages "MailKit.dll") | Out-Null

#Server and Mailbox Definitions
$mailserver = "mail.corp.com"
$username =  "email@corp.com"
$password = "password"

$cnn = New-Object MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient
$cnn.Connect($mailserver)
$cnn.Authenticate($username,$password)
$cnn.Inbox.Open([MailKit.FolderAccess]::ReadWrite)

$query = [MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::SubjectContains("Test")
#$orderBy = @([MailKit.Search.OrderBy]::Arrival)

#filter            
$uids = $cnn.Inbox.Search($query) #$orderby) not working yet

#download   
$msgs = $cnn.Inbox.Fetch($uids, [MailKit.MessageSummaryItems]::UniqueId -bor [Mailkit.MessageSummaryItems]::BodyStructure)

#do something

#move
$archive = $cnn.GetFolder("Archive.2018")
$cnn.Inbox.MoveTo($uids, $archive)  
$cnn.Disconnect($true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that MailKit had a reference to MimeKit dll, but there is no error loading MailKit.dll, so it's necessary to load MimeKit.dll also.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$home\.nuget\packages\MailKit\1.16.1\lib\net451\MailKit.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$home\.nuget\packages\mimekit\1.16.1\lib\net451\MimeKit.dll")
```

Comment: At first, I tried to load all dependencies with '[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile()'. But with Add-Type it worked without loading any of them.

Comment: This is my $PSVersionTable :

PSVersion                      5.1.15063.413
PSEdition                      Desktop

Comment: Add-Path didn't work for me but the above did and I also needed to load the MimeKit.dll to create a new SMTPClient object.